# php `preg_replace` only replace once time?

Tags: php, preg-replace

`preg_replace` only replace once time? i am tring to remoe unwanted words from a sentence,  why in this situation, "an" hasn't been replaced?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

in `modifier` part, what should i set?

```
$items = "This is an apple... ";
echo preg_replace('/ an | is /i',' ',$items);
//This an apple...
```

I need return "This apple...", thanx.

Comment: `/ an | is /` means: look for `_` followed by `a` followed by `n` followed by [ `_` or `_` ] followed by `i` followed by `s` followed by `_`. So it will essentially only match `_is_an_`  ---- `_` is [space] because SO wont markup properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it in parenthesises and surround it with word boundaries (`\b`):

```
$items = "This is an apple... ";
echo preg_replace('/\b(an|is)\b/i', ' ', $items);
//This     apple
```

You can remove extra spaces, by using the following:

```
$items = "This is an apple... ";
echo trim(preg_replace(array('/\b(an|is)\b/i', '/[ ]+/'), ' ', $items));
//                                              ^^^^^^
//This apple
```

Another example with the same code:

```
$items = "An apple, this is";
echo trim(preg_replace(array('/\b(an|is)\b/i', '/[ ]+/'), ' ', $items));
//apple, this
```

Comment: The main reason being that replacing `[space]is[space]` initially removes the trailing space from consideration for the `[space]an[space]`.

Comment: @MarcB However, it wouldn't work if the sentence was "An apple, this is".

Answer (score 0):

As commented by `@Mark B` your regex is not giving expected result because first replacement is happening for `[space]is[space]` and that removes the trailing space from the the next match `[space]an[space]` and hence you get `This an apple...`.

Here is the correct way to use preg_replace in your case using lookahead and lookbehind:

```
$items = "This is an apple... ";
echo '[' . preg_replace('/ *(?<= )(an|is)(?= ) */i', ' ', $items) . "]\n";
// OUTPUT: [This  apple... ]
```